# TableView with 2 colums by row , iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

Can anybody tell me how to create a tableview 
with two cells by colums in the Iphone SDK??

order in like this :

```
  _____________
  |  1  |   2  |
  |_____|______|
  |  3  |   4  |
  |_____|______|
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you give us an example what you'd like to put in the cells?

Comment: each cell will have a picture with two labels.. this will be a introductions for new "news", after the user press the cell it will  open a new view with all the "news"..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ios UITableView you can only have one column/cell. If you want more propertyes, in a same cell you need to create a custom table view cell by subcalssing UITableViewCell. In interface builder you can customize the layout. TUTORIAL:  http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Concrete example for your problem:

the .h file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIButton * column1;
    UIButton * column2;

    UILabel* column1_label1;
    UILabel* column1_label2;

    UILabel* column2_label1;
    UILabel* column2_label2;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton * column1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton * column2;

@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel* column1_label1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel* column1_label2;

@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel* column2_label1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel* column2_label2;

@end
```

the .m file:

```
#import "MyCell.h"


@implementation MyCell

@synthesize column1,column1_label1,column1_label2,column2,column2_label1,column2_label2;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        column1 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        column1.tag = 1;
        column1.autoresizingMask = 292;

        column1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        column1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,  self.contentView.bounds.size.height);


        column1_label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(column1.bounds.size.width*1/5,
                                                                             0,
                                                                             column1.bounds.size.width*4/5,
                                                                             column1.bounds.size.height/2)];

        column1_label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [column1 addSubview:column1_label1]; 

        column1_label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(column1.bounds.size.width*1/5,
                                                                             column1.bounds.size.height/2,
                                                                             column1.bounds.size.width*4/5,
                                                                             column1.bounds.size.height/2)];

        column1_label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [column1 addSubview:column1_label2]; 

        [self.contentView addSubview: column1]; 




        column2 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];


        column2.tag = 2;
        column2.autoresizingMask = 292;

        column2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        column2.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width/2, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,  self.contentView.bounds.size.height);

        column2_label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(column2.bounds.size.width*1/5,
                                                                             0,
                                                                             column2.bounds.size.width*4/5,
                                                                             column2.bounds.size.height/2)];

        column2_label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [column2 addSubview:column2_label1]; 

        column2_label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(column2.bounds.size.width*1/5,
                                                                             column2.bounds.size.height/2,
                                                                             column2.bounds.size.width*4/5,
                                                                             column2.bounds.size.height/2)];

        column2_label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [column2 addSubview:column2_label2]; 


        [self.contentView addSubview: column2];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

the usage in UITableViewController:

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 40;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    MyCell * mycell2 = ((MyCell*)cell);
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        [mycell2.column1 addTarget:self action:@selector(column1Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [mycell2.column2 addTarget:self action:@selector(column1Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    mycell2.column1_label1.text = @"column1_label1";
    mycell2.column1_label2.text = @"column1_label2";
    mycell2.column1.tag = indexPath.row*2;
    mycell2.column2_label1.text = @"column2_label1";
    mycell2.column2_label2.text = @"column2_label2";
    mycell2.column2.tag = indexPath.row*2 +1;
    return cell;
}

- (void) column1Selected: (id) sender
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc]                          
                          initWithTitle: @" Alert"                          
                          message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"button %d",((UIButton *) sender).tag]
                          delegate: nil                          
                          cancelButtonTitle: @" OK"                          
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];    
    [alert show] ;
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: my problem is, when the user touch, for example, the cell "1" it´s open the view_1, when cell 2, open view_2. There is any way to do that whit just a column by row with 2 supposed colums in the interface???

Comment: cells can be buttons, not labels, and you can add action handlers for buttons like this:  [column1 addTarget:self action:@selector("whenColumn1Selected:")  forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; where whenColumn1Selected: is a -(void) whenColumn1Selected { //do something when select}

Comment: and you can switch off the original cell selection if you don't need it in design.

Comment: i edited it to cell 1 and cell 2 behave as a button, replace the alerts with the navigation controller code and bingo!

Comment: fist, thanks a lot for your answer.... the problem is that each column will have a image whit two labels, this will required a view, correct?? can i add an action handlers for view???

Comment: Each view can handle touch, but with just signals, you need to subclass UIImageView and implement these signals:- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

Comment: And the UIImageView is a subbclass of UIView, so it can hold any subclass of view. Just use [myImageView addSubview: myLabel];

Comment: If you can Draw what you realy want I can suggest a workaround.

Comment: thanks again for your answer. i have to create 50 cell : 25 lines*2 columns.... with your example i have to create 50 methods??? there is another way??

Comment: No, you don't have to, the sender parameter holds the UIButton you touched. id type can hold any kind of object.

Comment: By the way event handlers are created, but thanks for the cell reuse, not all the cells are created. I recommend you to watch 10th lecture from this link:  http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395631522

Comment: thanks a lot, seriously... i´ve created a table whit 2 views and had the handlers to them... however i have another problem when i scroll the table to show the others row´s the app crash... Have any idea why????

Comment: I think it's a BAD ACCESS problem, what is the output on gdb?

Comment: Yes, but I need the gdb output. You can get the error from the call stack.

Comment: i have "already" solve the problem.. My NSMutableArray was in the state "autorelease".. just had the alloc/init to solve the problem.. thanks a lot Roki for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS6 you can use the [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you need iOS5 support [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) is a grid control that will give you what you are after.