# How to position UITableViewCell's content view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

how can I change the position of a `UITableViewCell` content view without subclassing 'UITableViewCell'?

putting `cell.contentView.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 50, 10, 10);` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to add multiple columns to your tableView, just see
[iPhone Multiple Columns in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506601/iphone-multiple-columns-in-uitableview)
and
[TableView with 2 colums by row , iphone/ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001460/tableview-whith-2-colums-by-row-iphone-ipad)

They use the way that subclassing your UITalbeViewCell, it's convenient to customize the cell's style. And the [`official doc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) may helps more.

**However, you can create a new view and set it as the `cell.contentView`, it'll replace the cell's contentView. Don't forget to set the cell's rowHeight if you want a smaller height one.**

Comment: cell.contentView has some rendering problems, the view keeps flickering when scrolling

Comment: @JAHelia I use the way of subclassing the UITableViewCell, haven't met the issue that you described. Maybe the UI or data is too large for your cell to rendering. I know there're some other views in cell: `backgroundView`, `selectedBackgroundView`, `image`, `accessoryView`. Maybe you can try if you still don't want to subclassing. :)